# VPC2007 SP1 Hotfix rollup kb958162

Tags: windows-7

The Microsoft download link for the VPC 2007 SP1 Hotfix Rollup(Kb958162) does not work.

I need both the 32 bit and 64 bit Hotfix rollups. The links are half way down the page. Does anyone have these or know of a place to get them?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/958162/description-of-the-hotfix-rollup-package-for-virtual-pc-2007-service-p

Comment: Those patches appear to only be applicable to Windows XP and Windows Vista.  You have indicated you are using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

> The Microsoft download link for the VPC 2007 SP1 Hotfix
>   Rollup(Kb958162) does not work.

Virtual PC 2007 is not supported Windows 7

> Microsoft® Virtual PC 2007 is not compatible with Windows 7.

[Official Unofficial Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/virtual-pc-2007-on-windows-7-64-bit/c7c0ddd8-167a-48e0-b0a9-f5c1e7bdbcbf)

You need to install [Windows Virtual PC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3702) instead.  The patches you are attempting to download cannot be installed on Windows 7.

Comment: VPC 2007 SP1 runs just fine on Windows 7 . I just need to upgrade the build by installing the hotfixs.